# Python 2 - How would you round up/down to the nearest 6 minutes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

There are numerous examples of people rounding to the nearest ten minutes but I can't figure out the logic behind rounding to the nearest six. I thought it would be a matter of switching a few numbers around but I can't get it to work.

The code I'm working with is located at [my Github](https://github.com/minorsecond/Timeclock/blob/dict/tc.py). The block I've got that isn't even close to working (won't give any output) is:

```
def companyTimer():
    if minutes % 6 > .5:
        companyMinutes = minutes + 1
    elif minutes % 6 < 5:
        companyMinutes = minutes - 1
    else:
        companyMinutes = minutes
    print companyMinutes
```

Looking at it now, I see that my logic is incorrect - even if it were working, the add and subtract 1 minute portion of the code doesn't make sense.

Anyway, I have no idea how to remedy this - could someone point me in the right direction, please?

PS - this is something I'm making for personal use at work.. not asking for help with my job but this will help me keep track of my hours at work. Don't want there to be any issues with that.

Thanks!

Comment: Where are the `minutes` and `companyMinutes` variables defined?

Comment: Should 0-2 round to 0 and 3-8 to 6, or rather 0-5 to zero and 6-11 to 6?

Comment: zachgates7 - minutes are defined within the timer function abave the companyTimer function.. I forgot to define it globally!

Comment: Finwood - great call. Didn't think about that one. Thanks!

Comment: Is the intent of "nearest 6 minutes" to obtain the nearest 1/10th of an hour? If so, my experience has been that most workplaces use rounding to the nearest 1/4 hour in their bookkeeping.

Comment: We report tenths of an hour here, ie 8:54 = 8.9 hours.

Comment: Ok, you've got a good start.  But what do you think `minutes % 6` should return if `minutes` is 3?  0? 6?

Comment: Is it 6 minutes as given in the question body, or 7 minutes as given in the title? It makes a big difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a general function to round to nearest `x`:

```
def round_to_nearest(num, base):
    n = num + (base//2)
    return n - (n % base)

[round_to_nearest(i, 6) for i in range(20)]
# [0, 0, 0, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18]
```

Explanation:

- `n % base` is the remainder left over when dividing `n` by `base`. Also known as the [modulo operator.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations)
- Simply subtracting `num%6` from `num` would give you 0 for 0-5, 6 for 6-11, and so on.
- Since we want to "round" instead of "floor", we can bias this result by adding half of the base (`base//2`) beforehand.

Comment: This is great! I'm sure this is CS101 stuff, but as a self-taught programmer I've gone entirely too long without knowing a general algorithm for this. Thanks!

Comment: just for completeness, do you mind explaining in a few words?

Comment: Thanks for the help, tzaman! Hopefully this answer will help others as well. Love this community.

Comment: Why did you use shift instead of divide?

Comment: @Paul Manta - Mostly habit, but it is also a marginally faster operation.

Comment: Use `//2` instead of `>>1` if you mean division by two. Bitshifts should be used only when handling bit patterns.

Comment: This does not work for an odd value of `base` if `num` is not an integer. `round_to_nearest(3.9, 7)` yields a result of `0` instead of `7`.

Comment: @JakeGriffin if you want this to be correct for floats just change to true division instead of integer division.

Comment: @tzaman, I know. Just wanted to call that issue out in case anyone tried to use it for floats. I also think this algorithm is overly complicated. I like to favor readability and self documenting code.. My answer is much simpler and more readable and works for ints and floats.

Comment: @JakeGriffin True, but it also involves float division and multiplication, and always returns floats, which is all overkill if you just need integer rounding. Still, useful to have both available, upvoted.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to round to the nearest 7 minutes (e.g. `round7(3.6) => 7`, `round7(17.4) => 14`), you can make use of Python's built in `round` function like so:

```
def round7(value):
    return round(value / 7.0) * 7.0

>>> round7(17.4999)
14.0
>>> round7(17.5001)
21.0
```

or, a more general function:

```
def round_to_nearest(increment, value):
    return round(value / float(increment)) * increment

>>> round_to_nearest(7, 17.4999)
14.0
>>> round_to_nearest(6, 21.0001)
24.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
def roundto6(minute):
    return int((minute+3) / 6) * 6

for i in xrange(13):
   print roundto6(i),

# 0 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 12 12 12 12 12 12
```

Comment: Careful: `//` is Python 3 syntax, if you're using Python 2 use `int(a / b)` instead

Comment: but only if both `a` and `b` are integers, if any of them is float `//` returns float as well in Python2

Comment: @Finwood: `//` works in Python 2 and 3. You should not use floats here.

Comment: @Finwood As far as I can tell, `//` works the same in Python 2.7 and 3.4 with regards to returning an int or a float.

Comment: There's also [`from __future__ import division`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/).

Answer (score 1):

simply use round, to round hours to 1 digit:

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 20, 4, 20, 578322)
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(round(time.mktime(w.timetuple())/3600,1)*3600)
datetime.datetime(2015, 4, 9, 20, 6, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

this is maybe not the smartest but a readable try :)

myNumber is your current minute

```
myList = range(0, 60, 6) # [0,6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54] # all accepted minutes 
myNumber = 8
print(min(myList, key=lambda x:abs(x-myNumber)))
```

Comment: `myList = range(0, 60, 6)` is a bit more understandable IMO. Also, generators only in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to consider would be:

```
def companyTimer(cm):
    minutes = (time.time() - starting_time) / 60
    print(minutes)
    if minutes % 6 >= 0.5:
        cm += 1
    return cm
```

Where `companyTimer` takes one argument: `companyMinutes`.

```
>>> import time
>>> starting_time = time.time()
>>> companyMinutes = 0
>>> companyTimer(companyMinutes) # will return 0 until 3 minutes have passed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're rounding up, the general formula

```
x + (roundtothis - x % roundtothis)
```

is of use to you.

I'm assuming that this is for rounding to nearest multiple of seven based on the question title, otherwise change to 6:
So:

```
def roundUpToSeven(minute):
    if ( minute % 7 == 0 and minute != 0 ):
        return minute
    else:
        return minute + (7 - minute % 7)
```

See a working example [here](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user39_j2hdzOfIVNkzy3X_2.py)

Comment: `min` is a builtin in Python and locals shadow it.  Best to pick a different name, IMO.

Comment: Is the behavior *at* a multiple of seven what you expect?  If minutes is 7, this returns 14 rather than 7.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want 2 to round to 0, 3 to stay at 3, and 4 to round to 6. Is this what you want?

```
def companyTimer(minutes, roundingNumber):
  remainder = minutes % roundingNumber

  if remainder > roundingNumber / 2:
    companyMinutes = minutes - remainder + roundingNumber
  elsif remainder < roundingNumber / 2:
    companyMinutes = minutes - remainder
  else:
    companyMinutes = minutes
  print companyMinutes
```

Comment: Although, I'm not sure why 3 would stay at 3, so I'm not sure if I am interpreting your question correctly. If you want 3 to round up change > to >= and if you want 3 to round down then change < to <=.